# jQuery Accordion Populate Table on Change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page with several accordion tabs on it and lots of data. I would like to fire a function that populates my tables when the user changes tabs. I am currently populating all the content at load time, which is really slow and inefficient. I have tried the following:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ beforeActivate: popdata }); - Activates only once.
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ activate: popdata }); - Acts as a click.
$( "#accordion" ).change() - Depricated
$( "#accordion" ).click(); - Acts as a click.
$( "#accordion" ).header(); - Not Applicable
$( "#accordion" ).trigger(); - Acts as a click.
$( "#accordion" ).click( function ( event ) { event.currentTarget }; - Only lists the div.
$( "#accordion" ).bind('accordionchange', yourFunction); - Depricated
```

The `click` and `activate` events fire when the user clicks anywhere on the accordion. I would need to limit it to the headers or tabs, but can't find the code to do so. The `beforeActivate` only fires once.

Is anyone able to suggest something? I've event tried to create my own event. Is there a way to filter the click event to determine if the user clicked on a `ui-accordion-header`?

Comment: Need a sample of HTML and also include the jQuery that normally works for you, Use the bracket button: `<>`. For more details refer to: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will admit I am "old school" when it comes to jQuery but I find the simple solutions the best.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
    // Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

    // Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
  });
});
```

All thanks go to this [simple accordion solution with jQuery](http://uniondesign.ca/simple-accordion-without-jquery-ui/)

Answer (score 0):

So the trick was to key into the classes. TY MrPickles for the hint. I can update the tables dynamically as follows:

```
$( ".accordion" ).click(function() {  }
```

accordion, ui-accordion, ui-accordion-header, ui-accordion-header-active, ui-accordion-header-collapsed, ui-accordion-content, ui-accordion-content-active are all good classes.

Reference Theming: https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/